# See http requests an app iOS (security)

Tags: ios, objective-c, security

I'm currently developing my app, developer and a friend told me that have saw all the http requests with the parameter (AFNetworking), how to hide this? And see how these requests? Thank you

Comment: Pass parameters over a secure channel. For instance, https. Https requests can still be intercepted with a fake trusted certificate though. So, you'll need certificates validation. I'm don't know how it's done, but it should give you a direction to look at

Answer (score 0):

Your app should connect to web services over an HTTPS connection. And [Apple will require HTTPS connections for iOS apps by the end of 2016](https://techcrunch.com/2016/06/14/apple-will-require-https-connections-for-ios-apps-by-the-end-of-2016/).

Check Apple's documentation : [Using Networking Securely](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/SecureNetworking/SecureNetworking.html)